# Search for the string in the column and mention the string by adding another column in the dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas

In my data I have several columns. In one of those columns I want to search for three different strings. After finding those strings I need to mention the rows which I have founded the strings by adding another column in the data and giving some name for which we Identified.

my data is like
this one column in my data which I want to do work

```
Campaign      
  Polestar - Remarketing - DN - BGLR
  Promenade - Remarketing - BLR
  Polestar -
  Polestar -BLR
  Urbana-Display-GSP-UK-July
```

and the Output want to be like

```
            Campaign                           REM
  Polestar - Remarketing - DN - BGLR        Remarkt
  Promenade - Remarketing - BLR             Remarkt
  Polestar -                                   -
  Polestar -BLR                                -
  Urbana-Display-GSP-UK-July                Mail
```

I want to find the string REM,Remarketing,GSP in the campaign table and mention into the new columns named REM and nitify these rows are having this string

> REM,Remarketing should mention 
>   Remarket GSP wantto mention Mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Campaign':['Polestar - Remarketing - DN - BGLR',
                               'Promenade - Remarketing - BLR',
                              'Polestar -',
                              'Polestar -BLR',
                              'Urbana-Display-GSP-UK-July']})

df['REM'] = '-'
df.iloc[df[df.Campaign.str.contains('Remarketing|REM')].index,1] = 'Remarket'
df.iloc[df[df.Campaign.str.contains('GSP')].index,1] = 'Mail'

df

#     Campaign                            REM
# 0 Polestar - Remarketing - DN - BGLR    Remarket
# 1 Promenade - Remarketing - BLR         Remarket
# 2 Polestar -                            -
# 3 Polestar -BLR                         -
# 4 Urbana-Display-GSP-UK-July            Mail
```

Comment: Hi leo, your code is running but not mentioning in the REM column

Comment: What are you getting in your `REM` column? Is it empty?

Comment: No, It's not empty I'm getting only the '-' symbol that we assigned

Comment: Copy the whole code snippet and try running it. The last two lines fill the expected values.

Comment: Can I know "df.iloc[df[df.Campaign.str.contains('Remarketing|REM')].index,1] = 'Remarket' " in this code what is the role of that last one (.index,1)

Comment: Since I've used `df.iloc` so I'm looking for index values where particular keyword occurs. Once I know the keyword occurs in a row, I choose only its `index` and pass it to the first argument of `.iloc`. Next, `1` is given because I'm selecting second column viz `REM` hence index of REM column.

Comment: Also, don't forget to upvote ;) once you reach 15 rep

Comment: With my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Using [np.select()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) Slightly faster than above solution.

```
c1 = df.Campaign.str.contains("Remarketing|REM")
c2 = df.Campaign.str.contains("GSP")
df['REM'] = np.select([c1, c2], ['Remarket', 'Mail'],'-')
#1.07 ms ± 75.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                             Campaign       REM
0  Polestar - Remarketing - DN - BGLR  Remarket
1       Promenade - Remarketing - BLR  Remarket
2                          Polestar -         -
3                       Polestar -BLR         -
4          Urbana-Display-GSP-UK-July      Mail
```